# Best way to check for variable's class in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an object which I am not sure is an NSString or not (could be NSNull, for example when reading a json into an NSDictionary) and I would like to get an NSString* if it is a valid string, nil otherwise.

Is there an accepted way of doing this except writing my own function?

```
+(NSString*)stringWithMaybeString:(id)maybeString {
    if ( [maybeString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
        return maybeString;
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method looks like the accepted way of doing this to me :)

Possibly you could add it to NSString using a category.

Comment: My method is of course inside an NSString category :) But I expected there to be something built in...

Comment: After some more experience with objective C, I can say that it just "rolls" the dynamic way. So while it's possible (and sometimes required) to know the static type of objects, it's just not so much in the mainstream. For example I used to have asserts in methods to check that the arguments type match the expected type, or aren't nil While it did catch some mistakes, doing this all the time puts a lot of burden on the code. It's just not what objective-c encourages you to do.